# Will Oracle DB Abort the query if the client exits midway?

Tags: oracle

I am a ( java ) developer, trying to understand the impact of expensive database queries on the Oracle database.

1. If I start a command-line query using sqlplus and if I terminate it ( ctrl-C ) after a few minutes, will the query complete inside the database ? ( Ctrl-C will cause the TCP socket to be closed )
2. is there any way to do the same ( close socket ) from within java ?

--sony

Answer (score 2):

You could cancel a running query from an other thread. I am pretty sure this can be done in Java see: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#cancel--

Comment: Thank you . I didnt know this